# how do I toggle a part of code that has an if-else statement?

Tags: javascript, if-statement, console, syntax-error, let

if i have a certain part of code I want to be flipped on and off, and I have a line of code that does that, why doesn't it want to work?

```
let b = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10)
let a = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10)
let x = true
if (x = true) {if (a >= 5) {if (b >= 5) {console.log('test 1'} else {console.log('test 2')}} else {console.log('test 3'} else {console.log('test 4')}
```

i tried something like that but on a larger scale, like maybe 5 of those for a game i was attempting to make, and i was hoping that the output would be something in the console like 'test 1', but all that was showing up was an error message.

Comment: Syntax error. You are missing at least one `)` in there. Also you want `if (x)`. `x = true` assigns to `x` (just like you do the line before).

Answer (score -1):

The `if` statement doesn't work because the comparison operator in Javascript is the triple equal sign and your code uses a single equal sign.

Also, there are some problems with your code that prevent it from running. These would generate errors.

- unmatched parentheses
- unmatched curly braces
- else not structured quite right

And some problems that are bad form

- missing semicolons
- formatting is a bit difficult to read

So I took some liberties and did some refactoring. You can see the code executing below. Hope this is useful to you.

```js
window.onload = function(){
    let a = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);
    console.log(`a = ${a}`);

    let x = true;

    if (x === true) 
    {
        if (a >= 5) {
        console.log('a >= 5');
        } else if (a >= 4) {
          console.log('a >= 4');
        } else if (a >= 3) {
          console.log('a >= 3');
        } else {
          console.log('a is less than 3');
        }
    } else {
        console.log('x is false');
    }
};
```